# Can I get back to Windows 10 from Windows 7 using windows.old file

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10, windows-7-x64

I recently installed Windows 7 over Windows 10 and that makes a windows.old file created in my hard disk.

I'm wondering if I could get back to Windows 10 using that exact file which has all my data "I don't want to keep windows 7".

Comment: Off topic. Consider asking it in superuser.com instead.

Comment: You now have the last good Windows release and you want to get back to 10? Now, that's novel!